# Is it possible to know the word count of other files in excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to have an Excel-Table with file paths of .docx documents. Besides this path, a word count should be listed.
For example:

```
+----------------------------+------------+
| File Path                  | Word Count |
+----------------------------+------------+
| C:\MyDocs\summary.docx     | 42         |
+----------------------------+------------+
| C:\MyDocs\certificate.docx | 1337       |
+----------------------------+------------+
```

So is it possible to just have a file path written in a field and Excel just reads out the word count with a macro or something similar

Comment: please review the [SO question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) for future questions. Not trying to speak for mehow, but +1 to his comment b/c your question does not demonstrate that you've already tried to solve the problem.

Comment: @AaronThomas, thank you for your suggestion. I do not own a very large knowledge about VBA and it could cost me days to find the answer fully on my own. I kept my question at least as simple as I could, so I hope it is no bother for you. Still, giving me a downvote for that is in my opinion a bit unkind and not constructive for beginners... Keep in mind that a lot of users on Stack Overflow are newbies, so please bring up a bit of sympathy for them if the question is well asked.

Comment: @muffin downvote was because question did not meet the question standards, not because I'm being unkind to newbies! Not having a large knowledge of VBA, the time involved in finding an answer on your own, and keeping a question simple are all fine. But the question does not meet the standards. In short, you've asked for someone to do your work for you - not helpful for newbies. Trust me, I know less than most here but this site is great to help you learn!

Comment: @AaronThomas, I see... I'll be more careful next time then! And as you say, it is true, this site is really great for learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started with this:

[image]

And used this macro to output the word count in the next column:

```
Sub GetMatchCount()
  Dim WordFileName As String

  WordFileName = Range("A1").Text

  With CreateObject("Word.Application")
    .Documents.Open (WordFileName)
    Text = .ActiveDocument.Words.Count
    .Quit
  End With

  Range("B1").Value = Text - 1
End Sub
```

[image]

---

To loop through a dynamic range try this.

[image]

```
Sub GetMatchCount()
  Dim numofrows As Integer
  numofrows = Sheet1.Range("A1").Offset(Sheet1.Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Row

  Dim rng As Range
  Set rng = Range("A2:A" & numofrows)

  Dim WordFileName As String

  For Each cell In rng
    WordFileName = cell.Text

    With CreateObject("Word.Application")
      .Documents.Open (WordFileName)
      Text = .ActiveDocument.Words.Count
      .Quit
    End With

    cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Text - 1
  Next
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: @muffin, keep in mind that the number of words you get includes all commas, dots and other special characters. They are recognised as separate `Word objects`.